# SSH From Vbox Server Into Host

Tags: ssh, sshfs

I am trying to use:

`#  sshfs -C hostuser@hostname:/home/users/Downloads/disk_image_files/ /vbox_mount_point_name`

but I get:

`read: Connection reset by peer`

I've tried a bunch of solutions editing the '/etc/hosts.allow' & '/etc/hosts.deny' but nothing seems to work.

Any advice appreciated.

**Additional Info**
(bad habit of forgetting this, sorry fellas behind on work, rushing to catch up)

ubuntu 20.04 host (vbox 6.1) & debian 10.5 vbox guest

I can ssh into the vm no problem, I can ssh from guest to host..

Here are my vbox settings
[image]

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu you have installed on host conputer and on virtual machine ?

Comment: Please, specify how you configured the network of the guest machine, especially the **Attached to:** selection. Are your host and guest Ubuntu machines? Which version? Can you try by using the host's IP address as obtained using the command `ip a` at host?

Comment: If you’re trying to mount a directory on the host with the VM, you may want to consider the “Shared Folders” feature that’s built into VirtualBox. This is what I do when testing stuff in my local Git directory against different Ubuntu Server versions and configurations. Two-way read/write and no network connection required 

Comment: @matigo  thanks for tip...using the shared folder, that I forgot I set up months ago, solved my immediate problem, but I'd still like to get an answer to the above question as I am trying to set up for full-time wordpress dev work... and a corrupt vdi is bound to happen again...  thanks